# dev- branch plugin forks being prompted for update

Tags: plugin-development, updates, composer

I'm currently using a fork of a plugin for my site, and using a "dev-[branch-name]" version specification in the composer "require" block, with a "vcs" repository definition for the fork location on github - basically looks like:

```
"repositories": [
  {
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://github.com/[forked-account/plugin-name]"
  }
],
"require": {
  "[original-account/plugin-name]": "dev-branch-name"
  ...
}
...
```

This worked fine for several months, but I'm suddenly now seeing a prompt to update to the latest version of the plugin on the author's "master" branch when running Craft update.  Has something changed with the requirements for the composer file version declarations for Craft to respect the "dev-" branch version as the preferred plugin version?

Answer (score 2):

I experience the same with https://github.com/Saboteur777/craft-support forked from https://github.com/jasonmccallister/craft-support (which is a fork of https://github.com/lukeyouell/craft-support).

Using `composer update` will not change "tracks" to the original plugin, so you are safe to update, the notification is a minor annoyance, though.

Comment: thanks otto.  yes, composer seems to respect it, but using craft update does not. problem is, it shows up in the dashboard as a plugin having an update available - easy for a client to accidentally update and blow away the customizations that have been made...

Comment: `craft update` would update to the "original" plugin?

Regardless the answer I would definitely suggest to disable admin updates, which will prevent any accidental updates by the client.

Comment: Opened a bug report: https://github.com/pixelandtonic/craftnet/issues/224